# Find uppercase strings with wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field `my_field` that is defined like this:

```
"properties" : {
    ...
    "my_field" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "no", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    ...
}
```

All lowercase strings that are stored in that field can be found with wildcard:

i.e. `kindergarten` can be found with `my_field:kinder*`

but all uppercase strings cannot be found with wildcard:

i.e. `KINDERGARTEN` can neither be found with `myfield:KINDER*` nor with `my_field:kinder*`

Is that the expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When changing the `index` to `analyzed`, all works fine, but I am wondering if the behaviour described above is a bug or not.

Answer (score 1):

You must set lowercase_expanded_terms to false in order to do case-sensitive search with wildcards. Like this: http://localhost:9200/test/_search?lowercase_expanded_terms=false&q=my_field:KINDER*

Answer (score 0):

I did quick test and everything looks correct to me.

I would try to test analysis on that field using `/_analyze` API to see that values really aren't lowercased.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/_analyze?field=my_field' -d {
    "test": "This Should Be Single Token"
}
```

Or try [Index Termlist Plugin](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-index-termlist) to see what tokens are actually stored in that field.